# Boostrap 3 and wrapper how to use it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new with Bootstrap 3 and just want to know how can I use .container class from Bootstrap with my own fixed wrapper.When I have fixed container of the page for example

```
    .wrapper {
width:960px;
}
```

and .container class from Bootstrap, how can I combine and use in my web page ?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
Text content here
</div>    </div>    </div>    </div>
```

is it correct ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

no need for the extra `div`. You could just do

```
<div class="container wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Text content here
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>

.wrapper {
    max-width: 960px;
}
```

Note that I used `max-width` in stead of `width`, or the responsiveness would be lost.